# Are questions about terminology on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

With technology comes technological jargon. Often, this is not written down and so is lost to antiquity; when it is used in written work the definitions are crucial to understanding the sentences in which they occur. It is important to preserve this information. (See: [`JARGON.TXT`](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/jargon.html))

However, questions about terminology of the time might collect lots of unsourced answers with terms used only by small groups of people. This is less of a problem with questions about defining a term than questions asking for terms.

Should questions about terminology be on-topic?

Answer (score 7):

I don't see why not.
It is true that terminology has changed over time as technology has changed.  We should have questions here to cover that.

You're right that there will be a lot of answers from people's memories, which may not have definitive answers from other sources.  However, it is our aim on this site to *be* the definitive source.  Therefore, people's memories should be captured.  The Q&A voting structure of SE will ensure that the best such answers will be upvoted by others with the same memory of the term.